# Can someone help with deleted 7zip archive restore

Tags: encryption, passwords, 7-zip

As the title says, I recently deleted an archive in 7z on windows 11, I went into the 7zip recycle bin and can see it but i cannot restore it.. Any time I right click and hit "Restore" nothing happens.. If I try to extract the archive or the files back out of recycle bin, I still can't get into it because of the encryption... Trying to open the files just gives me the error "this format isnt supported",  I even tried running Peazip extract and it gave me the password sign in but none of my passwords are working with it, even though I know I am entering the correct PW.

I don't understand how to "undelete" an archive or file from 7z recycle bin and be able to access my files again, it's extremely frustrating. I have tried everything my limited knowledge told me to try but no luck. The archive I am trying to restore is a .7z 256 encrypted folder.

Thank you.

Comment: 7-zip does not have a Recycle bin. Are you perhaps talking about Windows Explorer’s Recycle bin? Use Windows Explorer to interact with its Recycle bin, not some third-party software.

Comment: Hi Daniel, When I'm in 7-zip I can back out of the folders back to the root of whatever drive i'm using and I can see a recycle bin with items in it. I believe I'm looking at my deleted archives in here.. They are not present in the Windows recycle bin when I open it, Only in the 7zip recycle bin. There has to be a way to restore them and put them back in their right place. I tried moving them and tried extracting them back to their original locations in the drive but they will not work, I still cannot open them when they are in the correct folder. I think I am missing some way to "un delete"